# AngularJS - updating ng-class name dynamically

Tags: html, css, angularjs, animate.css

Using [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) with AngularJS. I'm trying to apply a class to the element on ng-click but the element doesn't get updated. I was trying multiple approaches (with updating scope values using functions etc.) with no joy. Basically, I'd like to add 'fadeIn', 'fadeOut' and 'flipIn', 'flipOut' to the animated element accordingly when button 1 or button 2 was clicked.

```
<button ng-click="animate = !animate; classIn = 'fadeIn'; classOut = 'fadeOut'" class="btn btn-default">Fade</button>

<button ng-click="animate = !animate; classIn = 'flipIn'; classOut = 'flipOut'" class="btn btn-default">Flip</button>

<div class="animated-wrapper">
  <h1 class="text-center animated" ng-class="{'{{classIn}}': animate, '{{classOut}}': !animate}">Animation</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks

EDIT:
After playing around with the code a little bit I come up with a solution (modifying a little bit @hadiJZ answer):

```
<button ng-click="setAnimateClass(animate = !animate, 'fadeIn', 'fadeOut')" class="btn btn-default">Fade</button>

<button ng-click="setAnimateClass(animate = !animate, 'bounceIn', 'bounceOut')" class="btn btn-default">Bounce</button>

<div class="animated-wrapper">
    <h1 class="text-center animated" ng-class="animateClass">Animation</h1>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.animate = true;

$scope.setAnimateClass = function (animate, classIn, classOut) {
  if (animate) {
    $scope.animateClass = classIn;
  } else {
    $scope.animateClass = classOut;
  }
};
```

Comment: try this

  
      ng-class="{'classIn': animate, 'classOut': !animate}"

Answer (score 1):

you must put class name in single quotation.
i put simple example.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.animate = true;
  vm.cssVal = "";
  
  vm.addFadeClass = function(animate){
    if(animate)
      vm.cssVal = "fadeIn";
    else
       vm.cssVal = "fadeOut";
    
    }
  vm.addFlipClass = function(animate){
    if(animate)
      vm.cssVal = "flipIn";
    else
       vm.cssVal = "flipOut";
    
    }
  
  
});
```

```css
.fadeIn{
  color: red;
  }

.fadeOut{
  color:blue;
  }
.flipIn{
  font-size:20px;
  }

.flipOut{
  font-size:40px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
 <button ng-click="vm.addFadeClass((animate = !animate))" class="btn btn-default">Fade</button>
<button ng-click="vm.addFlipClass((animate = !animate))" class="btn btn-default">Flip</button>


<div class="animated-wrapper">
  <h1 class="text-center animated" ng-class="vm.cssVal" >Animation</h1>
</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This will produce `<h1 class="text-center animated classIn"...` but I need `<h1 class="text-center animated fadeIn"...` instead

Answer (score 0):

You have redundant double curlies, change to:

```
<h1 class="text-center animated" ng-class="{'classIn': animate, 'classOut': !animate}">Animation</h1>
```

Comment: This will produce `<h1 class="text-center animated classIn"...` but I need `<h1 class="text-center animated fadeIn"...` instead

Comment: @user3925672 Then change your logic, I just showed you why your ng-class was failing. Change the conditions.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. After inspecting DOM of my example (with redundant curlies) I get: `<h1 class="text-center animated" ng-class="{'fadeIn': animate, 'fadeOut': !animate}">Animation</h1>` (for button 1) and after removing curlies i get `<h1 class="text-center animated classIn" ng-class="{'classIn': animate, 'classOut': !animate}">Animation</h1>` - which is fine, however I'd like to get `<h1 class="text-center animated fadeIn" ng-class="{'fadeIn': animate, 'fadeOut': !animate}">Animation</h1>` Not sure how conditions should be changed..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h1 class="text-center animated" 
    ng-class="{classIn: animate, classOut: !animate}">Animation</h1>
```

Comment: This will produce `<h1 class="text-center animated classIn"...` but I need `<h1 class="text-center animated fadeIn"...` instead

Answer (score 0):

Angular can take array as classes too :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

So you can just build your array with your controller and bind it to ngClass

```
ng-class="classArray"

$scope.classArray = [...]
```